# Websockets delay under Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I've created a simple WebSockets server which sends a tiny packet every 20 ms, just for testing purposes. Then I wrote a simple browser client in pure WebSocket api, which connects to the server and prints `Date.now()` every time it receives a packet.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
ws.onmessage = function(){ console.log(Date.now()); };
```

When I've launched the client in Google Chrome, the delay between the packets was consistent and always between 19 and 21 ms. When I've launched it under Firefox... uhh, delay was jumping between 3 and 114 ms. What's wrong with the Firefox and what's the workaround? Is there some kind of buffering enabled by default?

Tests were done on localhost under Linux, Firefox version is 38.0.5, packet size was 4 bytes, no additional code was running so garbage collector wasn't the issue. I've also launched both browsers simultaneously, results were the same.

Comment: For anyone else that has the same issue but it's not realted to `console.log` (like me), this has been raised as a bug on Mozilla's bug tracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1662694

Comment: In Firefox 81 on Ubuntu, there is no delay the first time, but if I refresh the page there is a 150-300ms delay between when `new WebSocket` is called and when FireFox calls the WS server. Seems to be related to whether there is an existing WebSocket object in the OPEN state. Maybe the cleanup is slow? No such issues in Chrome or Edge under Ubuntu/Windows/Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of testing, the result is quite funny - `console.log` implementation under Firefox is the root of all evil. Calling it frequently results in short browser hangs which makes all the timers and events go out of sync. When debugging timed events under Firefox, it's currently much better to store logs in an array and print it later.